# Listbox Data Printout Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, printing, listbox, userform

[See listbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztdMG.gif)I have created a userform with a list box that I can search and filter. After I have searched for specific information, I want to print the information out. My idea is to copy and paste the information from the list box on to another sheet, & then print that sheet out. However I am not getting the code right...

Please help....

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim shPrint As Worksheet
    Dim t As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Long
    
    Set shPrint = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Print")
    t = shPrint.Range("H10000").End(xlUp).Row
    
    shPrint.Range("A" & 2, "H" & t + 1).ClearContents
    
    For i = 1 To PatientDetails.ListDatabase1.ListCount - 1
    For x = 0 To 8
    shPrint.Cells(i + 1, x) = PatientDetails.ListDatabase1.List(i, x)
    Next x
    Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

If you need any additional information, please let me know!

[See Userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZQJK.png)

Comment: The line of code that has the error is "shPrint.Cells(i + 1, x) = PatientDetails.ListDatabase1.List(i, x)" . The error is: "Application-defined or object defined error"

Comment: Can you include the code where you created `PatientDetails` ?